# Make an object chase another object

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am trying to make an object chase another moving object and stop when it reaches the position of the object being chased. I have tried using TranslateonAxis as shown below

```
this.el.object3D.translateOnAxis(targetposition, distance);
```

to make the chaser reach the position of the target position (position of the object being chased) but the chaser object ends up moving in another direction altogether. I think the reason could be due to difference in world position and the local position of the objects.

Here is my code

```
    <a-scene physics="gravity: 0">
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="boat" src="../images/models/surfboard/scene.gltf"></a- 
         asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="orca1" src="../images/models/orca/scene.gltf"></a-asset- 
         item>
      </a-assets>
      <a-entity position="0 1.8 0">
          <a-camera id="camera" look-controls="enabled: false">
                <a-entity id="boats" position="0 -2 -4" rotation="0 -90 0" 
                scale=".02 .02 .02" gltf-model="#boat" static-body></a-entity>
          </a-camera>
      </a-entity>
<a-entity id="orca" position="-1 0.7 -40" gltf-model="#orca1" static-body move></a-entity>

</a-scene>
```

I try to move the #orca towards the #boats (which can be moved using WASD) using the move component. Code for that -

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('move', {
  schema: {
   speed: { type: 'number', default: 2 }
  },

  tick: function(t, dt) {
     var target = this.el.sceneEl.querySelector('#boats');
     var vec3 = new THREE.Vector3();
     var currentPosition = this.el.object3D.position;
     target.object3D.getWorldPosition(vec3);
     var  distance = dt*this.data.speed / 100;      
     this.el.object3D.translateOnAxis(vec3, distance);

     if (currentPosition.z > 30) {
        this.el.setAttribute('position', {
          z: -60
        });
      }

    }  
});
```

On a side note - I wish there were better explanatory material available explaining worldToLocal and LocaltoWorld methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need to get the boat's position by translating the world space to local space.

```
// Get orca's object in regard to the target object
vec3 = this.el.object3D.worldToLocal(target.object3D.position.clone())
```

To better understand this, consider the same setup seen from two points of view.
[image]

From the T point of view, it does not need to move towards [0, 0, 0]. It needs to calculate where the empty box is from its own point of view, which is [1, -0.7, 5]. Furthermore, the space is not only about position, but also about rotation (and scale, not important here). When T rotates, the empty box position will be different.

2) Check the distance using `THREE`s `a.distanceTo(b)`. If the distance is bigger than you want, move the orca:

```
var target = this.el.sceneEl.querySelector('a-camera'); // this should be in the init()
var vec3 = new THREE.Vector3();
var currentPosition = this.el.object3D.position;

// clone the position to operate on a copy
vec3 = this.el.object3D.worldToLocal(target.object3D.position.clone()) 
var  distance = dt*this.data.speed / 1000;      
var camFromOrca = currentPosition.distanceTo( target.object3D.position );

// if the distance is more than one meter, move the orca
if (camFromOrca > 1) {
  this.el.object3D.translateOnAxis(vec3, distance);
}
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8gLk2e3o/3/). Actually quite spooky :)

Comment: Adam, cannot thank you enough. Just a little more help needed. Could you please help me understand this worldToLocal/LocaltoWorld and what is it's significance. Also, getWorldPosition too. When I place entities by specifying their position attribute, for example: <a-box position="0 1 -2" color="red"></a-box> isn't that their world position as well as local position if there is no parent child relationship for that entity? In the above code, there is no parent for <a-box> so shouldn't local and world position be the same?

Comment: Also, are you on twitter or linkedIn so that I could stalk you there? :-)

Comment: @Niraj, sorry for the amateur picture, i have little time right now, but i hope its in any way helpful. Also thanks for the interest, i have a twitter (~gftru) but sorry to dissapoint, not much going on until i get myself to work on something bigger than simple experiments :) Let me know if the drawing is understandable, i can try to think of something better.

Comment: That picture is worth thousand words Adam. I understood the concept. Thank you. I owe you a beer!

Answer (score 1):

```
var vec3 = new THREE.Vector3();
var obj = this.el.object3D;
var targ = target.object3D;
obj.position.add(vec3.copy(targ.position).sub(obj.position).multiplyScalar(0.1));
```